# Creating XML document with namespace

Tags: python, xml, xml-namespaces, minidom

I am trying to generate an XML document using `xml.dom.minidom`.

What I need to get:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?><ns3:loginResponse xmlns:ns2="url1" xmlns:ns3="url2"><ns3:return>abcxyz</ns3:return></ns3:loginResponse>
```

I have tried this:

```
import xml.dom.minidom

doc = xml.dom.minidom.Document()
element = doc.createElementNS('url', 'ns25:getSecurityEvents')
element.setAttribute("xmlns:ns25","url")
main = doc.createElement('Text')eNode('Some text here')
main.appendChild(doc.createTextNode('Some text here'))
element.appendChild(main)
doc.appendChild(element)
print(doc.toprettyxml())
```

But I am getting output like this:

```
<ns25:getSecurityEvents xmlns:ns25="http://ws.v1.service.resource.manager.product.arcsight.com//securityEventService/">
<Text>Some text here</Text>
</ns25:getSecurityEvents>
```

I need to achieve two things:

1. Multiple namespace declarations in root node
2. Child node should be like `<ns25:Text>Some text</ns25:Text>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In minidom, namespaces are treated as if they were attributes. You can do it like this:

```py
import xml.dom.minidom

doc = xml.dom.minidom.Document()

doc_elem = doc.createElement('getSecurityEvents')
doc_elem.setAttribute('xmlns', 'http://ws.v1.service.resource.manager.product.arcsight.com//securityEventService/')
doc.appendChild(doc_elem)

text = doc.createElement('Text')
text.appendChild(doc.createTextNode('Some text here'))
doc_elem.appendChild(text)

print(doc.toprettyxml())
```

which prints

```
<getSecurityEvents xmlns="http://ws.v1.service.resource.manager.product.arcsight.com//securityEventService/">
    <Text>Some text here</Text>
</getSecurityEvents>
```

This is effectively what you want. If all the elements should be in the same namespace, you can make that the *default namespace* and drop the namespace prefixes. Here, `<Text>` is in the same namespace as `<getSecurityEvents>`.

When you want to write it to file, use something like this (write in binary mode & explicit set encoding):

```
with open('filename.xml', 'wb') as xml_file:
    xml_file.write(doc.toxml('utf-8'))
```

This makes sure the proper XML declaration is added and the file encoding is good.